# Get where is facing the cellphone in android

Tags: android, android-sensors, tilt-sensor

I'm trying to understand how can I know if the device's screen is facing the user or, for example, flat on a table with the screen looking up, or facing down, etc.

I'm not using the orientation sensor as it is deprecated I'm using the rotation matrix, I know pitch and roll values should be good the get that information, but before I get those values I need to remapcoordinatesystem and to know which Axle is the X and which one is the Y I need to know what is the screen facing.

For example: If the screen is facing the user I can use this mapping table

ROTATION_0       X     Y

ROTATION_90   -Y    X

ROTATION_180     -X   -Y

ROTATION_270     Y    -X

If the screen is facing the sky maybe I'll need to swap Y axle with Z axle, but I don't know how I can find out where is the screen facing.

Any ideas?

I'm also using this method I've find in the web (http://code.google.com/p/the-schwartz-unsheathed/source/browse/trunk/src/com/android/app/schwarz/PhoneOrientation.java?r=12)

```
 public static int getOrientation(float roll, float pitch) {
                int orientation = ORIENTATION_INVALID;

                if (Math.abs(roll) == 0.0 && Math.abs(pitch) == 0.0){
                    return ORIENTATION_INVALID;
                }

                if(roll >= -90 && roll <= -(90-mTolerance)){
                        orientation = ORIENTATION_FACE_LEFT;
                }
                else if(roll <= 90 && roll >= (90-mTolerance)){
                        orientation = ORIENTATION_FACE_RIGHT;
                    }

                if(pitch >= (90-mTolerance) && pitch <= (90+mTolerance)) {
                        if(orientation != ORIENTATION_INVALID){
                                orientation = ORIENTATION_INVALID;
                        }
                        else {
                                orientation = ORIENTATION_FACE_FORWARD;
                        }
                } else if(pitch <= -(90-mTolerance) && pitch >= -(90+mTolerance)) {
                        if(orientation != ORIENTATION_INVALID) {
                                orientation = ORIENTATION_INVALID;
                        }
                        else {
                                orientation = ORIENTATION_FACE_BACKWARD;
                        }
                }

                if((roll >= -mTolerance && roll <= mTolerance)) {
                        if((pitch >= -mTolerance && pitch <= mTolerance)) {
                                if(orientation != ORIENTATION_INVALID) {
                                        orientation = ORIENTATION_INVALID;
                                }
                                else {
                                        orientation = ORIENTATION_FACE_UP;
                                }
                        } else if((pitch <= -(180-mTolerance) && pitch >= -180) || (pitch >= (180-mTolerance) && pitch <= 180)) {
                                if(orientation != ORIENTATION_INVALID) {
                                        orientation = ORIENTATION_INVALID;
                                }
                                else {
                                        orientation = ORIENTATION_FACE_DOWN;
                                }
                        }
                }

                return orientation;
        }
```

Anyone has one better?

Comment: What if someone is reading the screen upside down - e.g. when lying in bed? Then this solution doesn't work at all, right?
You could also do face recognition though it's a bit overkill I guess...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Accelerometer, because it gives the x-y axis of the device, so you can get where the device is facing.

Comment: That's not correct, it's only correct if the screen is facing the user, if the screen is facing the sky is different. The screen coordinate system doesn't change, but the sensors coordinate system does. That's why we should use remapCoordinateSystem.